# Visual Studio - How to disable autoformat/correct while running macro?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, autocorrect

When running a macro that changes the selected text, tags are automatically closed and the text formatted. How can I prevent that from happening?

For example, wrapping text in a tag:

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = String.Format("<tag>{0}</tag>", DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text)
```

Ends up with two closing tags:

```
<tag>Text</tag></tag>
```

Even stranger, multiple lines fails:

```
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
```

An ends up as

```
<ul>            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
                        <li>Three</li></li></ul>
```

How can I prevent that? As can be seen by the last example, the formatting is wrong and there is an extra `</li>`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to insert the text rather than assigning it:

```
Try
    DTE.UndoContext.Open("InsertSomeCode")
    Dim ts As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
    ts.Insert(String.Format("<tag>{0}</tag>", ts.Text))
Finally
    DTE.UndoContext.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to open a undo transaction for your edit.  This should suspend all formatting operations until the transaction is complete.  This will allow you to do several edit operations before a format.

Here is the documentation OpenLinkedUndo method

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivslinkedundotransactionmanager.openlinkedundo(VS.80).aspx

Comment: No example code there... would want to undo the macro action (if this stops that from happening that is)